# Trying to understand the idea behind path independence for line integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I’m trying to grasp the idea behind the line integral for conservative vector fields. If I have some vector valued function $F$ which can be represented as $\nabla f$ then I have a conservative field. Now what I’m not fully comprehending is that why the integral $$\int_C F \ dr$$ is path independent. I’ve looked several explanations for this and the analogy for FTC is quite clear so this makes sense in ”symbolic” form, but all the explanations I’ve seen usually explain this via some physical experiement such as traversing to the top of a mountain and since the gravitational field is conservative the work done to get to the top would be independent of the path I’m taking. I’m not a physicist and even this doesn’t quite make sense, I would assume that the work done from the gravitational field to me would be much greater if I start to go for example up sideways instead of directly walking up the mountain? If work is defined as $W=f \cdot d$ wouldn’t the $d$ be much greater if I’m taking a longer path and thus $W$ would get larger?

Is there some other kind of intuition for this that wouldn’t rely so much on physical concepts such as the gravitational, electric or magnetic fields?

Edit: Ah perhaps if I’m taking a path sideways the field vectors would be directed towards me at some angle and thus wouldn’t do as much work as if they would be directed right towards me?

Comment: Well, you can always prove it... take two independent paths and combine them together to create a closed path, what is the value of such  integral on a closed path?

Comment: Well $0$ if the paths $C_1$ and $C_2$ are closed. They would just cancel out.

Comment: I am not talking about closed paths, suppose that $C_1,C_2$ are paths from $a$ to $b$. Then the path that made of  $C_1$ and $C_2$ backwards is a closed path. Indeed, the integral is 0. But you can use the additivity of the integral’s domain to conclude that the integral over $C_1$ is the same as the integral over $C_2$.

Comment: Is that clear or you want me to give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Perhaps what bothers me the most is that if $C_2$ would be of much greater length than $C_1$... Is it the case that even though $C_2$ would be of greater length, if they’re both from $a$ to $b$ they form a closed path and thus I can find a point on the path that would make them the same length and therefore they would cancel out?

Comment: Not exactly... Length doesn’t matter. All that matters is the value at the *endpoints*, but in a closed path, the endpoints are the same. This is a similar idea to the one of the fundamental theorem of calculus - in order to xompute the area under the curve, you only care about the values (of the anti derivative) in the endpoints, and you don’t really care about how the curve exactly looks like

Comment: Your "ah perhaps" is precisely why length is not what matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main definitions for the definition of a conservative vector field $\mathbf{F}:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$:

- $\exists \Phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R} \text{ such that }\mathbf{F}=\nabla\Phi$
- In the special case that $d=2$ or $d=3$, we can also say $\nabla\times\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{0}.$
- And of course often given as a definition is $\oint\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})\boldsymbol{\cdotp}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=0$, which is what you're asking about.

I'll show that the first and third definitions imply the second. Let's start with the first. Letting $O$ be a closed smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^d$,

$$\oint_{O} \mathbf{F}\boldsymbol{\cdotp}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=\oint_{O} \nabla\Phi(\mathbf{x})\boldsymbol{\cdotp}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$$
Seeing as $O$ is smooth, we can parameterize it as $O=\{\mathbf{x}(t)~|~t\in(0,T)\}$, with of course $\mathbf{x}(0)=\mathbf{x}(T)$. With this in mind, we can represent the line element as
$$\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}'(t)\mathrm{d}t$$
So then
$$\oint_{O} \nabla\Phi(\mathbf{x})\boldsymbol{\cdotp}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=\int_0^T \nabla\Phi(\mathbf{x}(t))\boldsymbol{\cdotp}\mathbf{x}'(t)\mathrm{d}t$$
However, $\nabla\Phi(\mathbf{x}(t))=\left(\nabla\Phi\circ\mathbf{x}\right)(t)$, and so via the chain rule,
$$\mathrm{D}_t\left(\Phi\circ\mathbf{x}\right)(t)=\left(\nabla\Phi\circ\mathbf{x}\right)(t)\boldsymbol{\cdotp}\mathbf{x}'(t)=\nabla\Phi(\mathbf{x}(t))\boldsymbol{\cdotp}\mathbf{x}'(t)$$
Hence,
$$\oint_{O} \nabla\Phi(\mathbf{x})\boldsymbol{\cdotp}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=\int_0^T \mathrm{D}_t\left(\Phi\circ\mathbf{x}\right)(t)\mathrm{d}t$$
So by FTC,
$$=\left(\Phi\circ\mathbf{x}\right)(T)-\left(\Phi\circ\mathbf{x}\right)(0)$$
$$=\Phi(\mathbf{x}(T))-\Phi(\mathbf{x}(0))=0.$$
Which as per our parameterization, is precisely zero. One can take this idea further to say that for any smooth curve $C$, not necessarily closed, parameterized as $C=\{\mathbf{x}(t)~|~t\in[a,b]\}$ that
$$\int_C \nabla\Phi(\mathbf{x})\boldsymbol{\cdotp}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=\Phi(\mathbf{x}(b))-\Phi(\mathbf{x}(a))$$
That is to say, it only depends on the endpoints.

In the special case of two or three dimensions, showing (3) implies (2) is practically instant. Let $\Omega$ be the region enclosed by $O$, that is to say, $\partial\Omega=O$. Using Stokes's theorem, one can say that
$$\oint_O \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})\boldsymbol{\cdotp}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=\int_{\Omega}\left(\nabla\times\mathbf{F}\right)\boldsymbol{\cdotp}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{n}$$
But, the RHS is trivially zero since by assumption $\nabla\times\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{0}$. Therefore the LHS is zero as well.