# Proving the converse of path independence due to the vector field being conservative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

We know that if a vector field is conservative, then the work done by the vector field between any two points is independent of path. How can we prove the converse? That is, if the work between any two arbitrary points is independent of path, then the vector field is conservative.

Comment: This is known as Poincaré‘s Lemma and the proof is far from trivial. Also, this does not hold for every Domain oder the Vector Field

Comment: @Meowdog no, the statement is correct as is; for a proof, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3967655/568204). The point is we’re assuming independence of ***all paths***, so we can introduce a well-defined potential function (i.e modulo basic analysis details, the proof is ‘straightforward’). Note carefully that we’re not just assuming that the integral vanishes over all ‘rectangular loops with sides parallel to coordinate axes’. Hence, this statement is stronger than Poincare’s lemma.

Comment: You are right,  I misread. Thank you very much!